# "Plugin Scala is incompatible with this installation" error with IntelliJ 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

From Browse Repositories in IntelliJ 14, the newest Scala plugin is version 1.5.2.

[image]

From the Scala plugin homepage for IntelliJ, the latest version (as of Aug 10, 2015) is 1.7.4. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1347

However, when I tried to install it from "Intall plugin from disk ..." after downloading `scala-intellij-bin-1.7.4`, I got this error:

[image]

[image]

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the link that you've provided you can see that compatible Intellij Idea builds for `1.7.4` version are `142.3553 — 143`. The latest 14 Idea build has version lower than `142` - so it's incompatible with this plugin version. There is already *EAP Intellij Idea 15* which you can download and install new scala plugin version on it.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue with 2020.2.4 Intellij IDEA. I just uninstalled the plugin and installed it again. Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

1. Go in settings - `ctrl` + `shift` + `s`
2. `Plugins`
3. `Updates` at the top
4. Push the button `Update all`
   Done!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to directly install the Scala plugin from the marketplace. However, if you can't do it for some reason (say, HTTP proxy related), you can download the plugin and install in the IntelliJ. Finding the correct plugin is little tricky, I provided a screenshot below:

[image]

The supported products are provided and we will need to look closely for that. This plugin will only work for those products.